# haxe, phone gap, jquery mobile instead of native app

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, haxe

I've learning Android development using java for 10 month and I've thought about start in windows phone and iOS but lately I've read about phone gap and jquery mobile which allows you to write your application and run it on any platform and it would be very great.

Is it really worth learning to use that tools or should I use c# and objective-c in each case?
if it's so is it easy to learn, I mean there are documentation to start..

I've also heard about Haxe but I don't get it at all the way it works

Thanks in advance

Comment: This has been widely discussed here and elsewhere. Please do a bit of research before asking such open-ended questions. Then ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you talk about is well-documented. If you use crossplatform tools you get crossplatform applications, if you use platform tools you get applications for one platform. From the other point of view, crossplatform tools will rarely allow you to get full benefits of each of platform: some things would be slower, some things would be abstracted away. The choice is up to you.

However, minding the nature of your question, I doubt you have enough knowledge nor experience for working with any of this platforms on level higher than barely acceptable. So I'd recommend you to start from the start, and learn some C or low-level java( = java assembler and bytecode) first.